# How can we pass live video MediaStream captured from web camera from angular to nestjs backend solution using socket.io-stream and socket.io-client

Tags: angular, socket.io, nestjs, socket.io-client, socket.io-stream

Could you please advise based on your experience?

How can we pass live video MediaStream captured from web camera from angular application to nestjs backend using socket.io-stream and socket.io-client?

Currently I have empty object passed to backend:

```
{
  mediaStream: {},
  participantId: 'eUCQQZHiB3LQQJLSAAAT',
  roomName: '93d8c4628ab17026d813152b'
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you try to find how to convert your mediastream into frames both audio and video and the pass it to your websocket to reconstruct them on the other side but you'll need to implement a jitter buffer for that and this will add latency